# XXXSummaryStatistics new constructor in java-10

Tags: java, java-stream, java-10

I see that `java-10` adds a constructor for `IntSummaryStatistics` (`LongSummaryStatistics` and `DoubleSummaryStatistics`) that takes 4 parameters that are `count`, `min`, `max` and `sum`.

I understand why the no-args constructor exists, so that it would be used in reduction, like :

```
 ..stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Class::someFunction))
```

That makes sense, but why is there a need to add the constructor with 4 parameters? (I made an assumption in my own answer, but if that is not the case I would gladly retract it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that while such an optimization does not happen today in the reference implementation, an operation like `IntStream.rangeClosed(from, to).summaryStatistics()` does not need to actually iterate over all values.

It could simply return
`new IntSummaryStatistics((long)to-from+1, from, to, ((long)from+to)*((long)to-from+1)/2)`.

As said, this optimization does not happen today, but is an example that sometimes, there are ways to calculate such a statistic without having to iterate every value, so it was a significant limitation that the only way to fill a xxxSummaryStatistics was `accept​`ing individual values (and `combine`, but that requires an already existing statistics instance that must have been filled somehow).

Comment: since I was really interested in "future" uses, this is what IMO answers my question

Answer (score 5):

I've tried to search the sources if these constructors are used somewhere and I could not.

So my only thought would be that it is used to constructor such an Object manually. Suppose that we have a method that computes all these average, min, max, count and instead of returning an `array/List` of 4 parameters, you could return an `IntSummaryStatistics`, previously this was not possible. So, I guess, this just extends the API without having (yet?) any internal usages.

---

From the [relative CSR](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8190381) precisely :-

***Problem*** :
It is not possible to reconstruct `*SummaryStatistics` from it's recorded values. *For example to be "cloned" or transmitted in a serial form and reconstituted*.

***Solution*** :
Add constructors to `*SummaryStatistics` accepting pre-recorded state.

Comment: Correct. The rationale is described here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178117

Answer (score 2):

Other than the answer for the usage(need) of such a constructor, to be concerned about the correctness of the API implementation, one should really take into consideration of the called out loud ***API Note*** such that creation of [such instances](http://download.java.net/java/jdk10/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html#%3Cinit%3E(long,int,int,long)) are under certain thoughtful considerations as(emphasis mine) -

> If the `count` is zero then the remaining arguments are ignored and an empty instance is constructed.

Example -

```
var intsummstats = new IntSummaryStatistics();
// creates the following stat
=> IntSummaryStatistics{count=0, sum=0, min=2147483647, average=0.000000, max=-2147483648}

// and the  following results into a similar stat as well
var anotherintsummstats = new IntSummaryStatistics(0, 12, 100, 1000);
=> IntSummaryStatistics{count=0, sum=0, min=2147483647, average=0.000000, max=-2147483648}
```

> If the arguments are inconsistent then an `IllegalArgumentException`
>   is thrown. The ***necessary consistent argument*** conditions are:
>
> - count >= 0
> - min <= max

But then since this doesn't cover all types of checks over the `count`, `sum`, `max` and `min` combination of the values the user can put in, there is this statement(which I found while playing around with the constructor)

> The enforcement of argument correctness means that the retrieved set
>   of recorded values obtained from an `*SummaryStatistics` source
>   instance ***may not be a legal set of arguments for this constructor due
>   to arithmetic overflow of the source's recorded count of values***. The
>   *consistent argument conditions are not sufficient to prevent the
>   creation of an internally inconsistent instance*. An example of such a
>   state would be an (IntSummaryStatistics) instance with: count = 2, min = 1, max = 2, and sum
>   = 0.

and to add to it, such incorrectly created instances when [`combine`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk10/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html#combine(java.util.IntSummaryStatistics))d with other `*SummaryStatistic` could result into an illegal set of arguments further.

Comment: darn! I never upvoted this answer, totally my bad